# EntityFramework + Firebird как подключить - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

Добрый день! Уже целый день пытаюсь подружить Firebird с EntytiFramework и не получается. Делал всё по инструкции https://habrahabr.ru/post/278405/

С помощью менеджера пакетов NuGet следующие пакеты:

- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
- EntityFramework
- EntityFramework.Firebird

Далее создаю элемент "Модель ADO.NET EDM". И на этапе выбора таблиц из бд полностью тормозит студия(скринш).

В какую хоть сторону смотреть подскажите..?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю тормозит мастер моделей. Пробовали в ручную создать модель?

Comment: Да, именно мастер тормозит. Вручную это как?

Comment: Сколько у вас таблиц? Судя по прогресс-бару, их много. Неудивительно, что процесс извлечения схемы данных и генерирования классов идёт долго. Может, просто подождать, пока завершится работа?

Comment: где-то около 200 приблизительно наверное. Но если выбираю одну таблицу для включения в модель, все равно тормозит. Если вообще не выбираю, тоже тормозит @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 1):

#### Вариант 1.

Самый сложный и муторный. Это набивка всех моделей в ручную и маппинг к ним:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("USERS")]
class Users
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("LOGIN")]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Плюс этого подхода в том, что классы и свойства можете называть как вам удобно.

#### Вариант 2.

Удобство тут сомнительное, но если сумеете разобраться, то должно получиться довольно быстро.
На **MSDN** есть **[пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-use-edmgen-exe-to-generate-the-model-and-mapping-files)** использования `EdmGen.exe`. По идее, с его помощью можно создать те же модели, которые создаются в `EDM Wizard`.

Смотрите также по `EdmGen.exe`:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387165(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb896343(v=vs.100).aspx